# Data is In database but it is still saving the form

Tags: django

```
 if request.method == "POST":
            form = HayvanEkle(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                if request.POST.get("alan") in Hayvan.objects.all():
                    return redirect("/")
                else:
                    form.save()
                    return redirect("/")
```

"alan" is in the database but it is still saving the form. What should I do?

---

models.py:

```
 class Hayvan(models.Model):
        alan = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
        satışsırası = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
        hayvannumarası = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
        kesimsırası = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
```

Comment: Please share your `Hayvan` model. What is `alan`? The primary key of a `Hayvan`?

Comment: Well, `Hayvan.objects.all()` is a sequence of `Hayvan` objects, which probably won't equal whatever `alan` is from your form. But even so, you're supposed to enforce uniqueness with database constraints, not by reading all records from the database into Python and comparing them all there!

Comment: `alan = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=True)` — Done. — Though, depending on how you want to handle blank/null uniqueness, you might need a slightly more involved constraint.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check if there already exists a record with the value for `alan` with:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = HayvanEkle(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if Hayvan.objects.filter(alan=request.POST.get('alan')).exists():
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
```

You might want to set the `alan` field on `unique=True` such that the database will enforce this:

```
class Hayvan(models.Model):
    alan = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True)
    # …
```

Note that if an item for the given `alan` already exists, you will *not* update that record with the form. You can do this by constructing a form with `HayvanEkle(request.POST, instance=instance_to_update)`.